# output an array in Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have pieced together the following code so I can trim the leading and trailing spaces from every cell in a worksheet.  In order to keep the table properties I need to make sure I don't mess with the header row.  When I run this everything is deleted except the header row.  What am I doing wrong?

This is my first time dealing with arrays.  When I tried this without the array the code would take a while to read and rewrite every cell in the sheet.  The array is a whole lot faster, I just don't understand how to use it as well.

```
Dim arrData(), arrReturnData() As Variant
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim i, j, lRows, lCols As Long

Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1) 'don't mess with the header row
arrData = rng.Value

lRows = rng.Rows.Count
lCols = rng.Columns.Count

ReDim arrData(1 To lRows, 1 To lCols)
ReDim arrReturnData(1 To lRows, 1 To lCols)

For j = 1 To lCols
    For i = 1 To lRows
    arrReturnData(i, j) = Trim(arrData(i, j))
    Next i
Next j

rng.Value = arrReturnData
Set rng = Nothing
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning

`arrData = rng.Value`

And then redimming it. hence all the values are gone.

BTW, you don't need the `ReDim arrData(1 To lRows, 1 To lCols)` at all. When you store the excel range to variant array, the array gets re sized automatically.

Tried and Tested

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim arrData(), arrReturnData() As Variant
    Dim rng As Excel.Range
    Dim i, j, lRows, lCols As Long

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1) 

    lRows = rng.Rows.Count
    lCols = rng.Columns.Count

    ReDim arrReturnData(1 To lRows, 1 To lCols)

    arrData = rng.Value

    For j = 1 To lCols
        For i = 1 To lRows
            arrReturnData(i, j) = Trim(arrData(i, j))
        Next i
    Next j

    rng.Value = arrReturnData
    Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: In that case I would highly recommend [THIS](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) link for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Preserve

```
Redim Preserve arrData(1 To lRows, 1 To lCols)
```